# Can you restrict a string to a set of permitted strings in YANG?

Tags: yang

Can we have a statement in YANG which constraints the user input string to one of the strings which are permitted? I saw that one can use `pattern` to match a certain regex, but what if we have strings like "apple", "orange", "strawberry" which are permitted, and the product below must be a member of this set of permissible strings?

```
leaf product{
  type string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YANG has a built-in type named `enumeration`, which serves the exact purpose you describe.

```
leaf product {
  type enumeration {
    enum apple;
    enum orange;
    enum strawberry;
  }
}
```

This is the type you should use if permitted values are members of a set of string constants. The specifics of the type may be found in [RFC 7950, Section 9.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7950#section-9.6).

Technically speaking, you could also use the `string` built-in type and restrict it with a `pattern` that takes a regex argument such as `apple|orange|strawberry`, but you'd be using the wrong tool for the job.

Advantages of using `enumeration` instead of above:

- the lexical representation of an `enumeration` value is a string - one of the `enum`s
- each `enum` may be documented with `description`/`reference`
- each `enum` is (either explicitly or implicitly) assigned a `value`, an integer that may be used internally by implementations to identify the associated string
- each `enum` may get an `if-feature` statement (YANG version 1.1)
- improved readability and easier to maintain

Comment: Right. The only drawback with this is that the tool which generates cpp code from the yang file, will "translate" this type to an enum, whereas I need it as a string. Otherwise, conversion methods between the two are needed.

Comment: I abandoned this approach for other reasons, but thanks for taking time to answer this